# The bootloader is installed on another drive

Tags: partitioning, 22.04, bootloader

I was installing Ubuntu 22.04 on my external SSD, and since I went with the default partitioning options, the installer installed the boot loader on the SSD of my PC instead! Now even if the external SSD is not connected, the Ubuntu OS is in the boot menu as an option beside the original OS on my PC. I haven’t tested it yet but I guess if I connect the external SSD to another computer, it won’t be able to boot it. How should I fix this please?

**UPDATE**

The original OS on my PC is fine and it boots correctly. The problem is with my external SSD now. I want to be able to boot from the external SSD for the Ubuntu instead of booting from the internal SSD of my PC.

Comment: I really wish they would fix this bug, Please add to it. I now am posting this a couple of times a day. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 Various work arounds in bug report. You must partition with gpt in advance & have an ESP (FAT32 with esp flag) on external drive. https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/1056079#1056079 You can add ESP, edit fstab with new ESP's UUID & reinstall grub when booted into it.  Or use Boot-Repair after creating ESP.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. Can you please provide an step-by-step guide on how to do all that? @oldfred

Comment: Do what? Bug report has multiple ways, link has several ways (same as those in bug report). If not used to using gparted to create a new partition & editing fstab, easier to just reinstall using one of the install work arounds. Either disconnect internal drives or disable in UEFI settings or use gparted from Ubuntu live installer to remove boot flag from internal drive temporarily as per link.